# Read file, replace a word and write to a new file in Java

Tags: java, regex, file-io, arraylist

I am trying to read a text file which I then put into an ArrayList and then go through that ArrayList and replace any occurrences of the word "this" with "****". I then want to put this modified ArrayList back into a new file with the newly edited text.

The applications currently reads the lines into the ArrayList correctly and writing to the new file works. However, replaceWords method doesn't appear to be functioning as expected i.e. this is not being replaced by ****. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package com.assignment2s162305.answers;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Question27 {

    private List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    // read original file to an ArrayList
    public String[] readOriginalFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }

    // replace words with ****
    public void replaceWords() {
        Collections.replaceAll(lines, "this", "****");
        System.out.println(lines);
    }

    // write modified ArrayList to a new file
    public void writeToNewFile() throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        for (String str : lines) {
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
    }

}

package com.assignment2s162305.answers;

import java.io.IOException; 

public class Question27Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Question27 question27object = new Question27();

        String filename = "Hamlet2.txt";  

        try {  
            String[] lines = question27object.readOriginalFile(filename);
            System.out.println("______ORIGINAL DOCUMENT______\n");
            for (String line : lines) {  
                System.out.println(line);  
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            question27object.replaceWords();
            question27object.writeToNewFile();
        } catch(IOException e) {  
            // Print out the exception that occurred  
            System.out.println("Unable to create "+filename+": "+e.getMessage());                
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `replaceWords` method has a bug. To fix it, you need to loop through the lines and do the replacement in each line. What you have implemented is to replace all lines which are equal to `"this"` with `****`. So this works OK but is not what you wanted.

This this code. This will fix it.

```
public void replaceWords() {
    ArrayList<String> lns = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String ln : lines){
        lns.add(ln.replaceAll("this", "****"));
    }
    lines.clear();
    lines = lns;
    System.out.println(lines);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it. Now that I read your fix I can see where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines of text into your array `lines`.  However, [`Collections.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#replaceAll%28java.util.List,%20T,%20T%29) doesn't search inside the string to replace the word `"this"`; it will just test if the entire line is equal to `"this"`, which it certainly isn't.

> Replaces all occurrences of one specified value in a list with another. More formally, replaces with newVal each element e in list such that (oldVal==null ? e==null : oldVal.equals(e)).

Example:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
lines.add("This");
lines.add("this");
lines.add("THIS");
lines.add("this won't work.");
Collections.replaceAll(lines, "this", "****");
System.out.println(lines);
```

Output:

```
[This, ****, THIS, this won't work.]
```

You can split your lines into words, and attempt `Collections.replaceAll` on the `List` of words.

Or, you can use [`String`'s `replace` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which will match the word within the line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
    lines.set(i, lines.get(i).replace("this", "****"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From replaceAll method javadoc:

> Replaces all occurrences of one specified value in a list with
>   another. More formally, replaces with newVal each element e in list
>   such that (oldVal==null ? e==null : oldVal.equals(e)). (This method
>   has no effect on the size of the list.)

It means, that you are trying to replace String instance holding exactly `"this"` text by String  instance holding `"****"` text instead of replacing text inside String object. Note that String is immutable.

You have to iterate list of Strings and replace text using `String#replace` or `String#replaceAll` methods.